# Specifying an Invoice Class via IPP

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Invoice in QB online can easily be assigned a 'class', which helps to divide up income / expenses.

These classes are likely a "ReferenceType", as Classes are pre-defined list. I don't see any way to update this field via IPP. Am I missing something? I see that you can set the ClassRef for each individual line, but isn't this something different?

Any clarification is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a bug with Intuit's platform to me. I would submit a support incident at https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed there is a problem and both answers above are correct depending on what version of QBO you are hitting.

Looking at a Classic QBO company file, classes are at the line level and not at the invoice level.

But if you look at Harmony QBO company file (new format), classes are at the invoice level and not line level.

I have submitted bugs to QBO and for the docs to add clarifications.

Comment: After some more digging, you CAN have classes at the line level. You need to go in to the Preferences for the Classes and select Detail Line and not Transaction. But there is still a bug for V3 not having classes at the transaction level.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way for me to be updated on the response from the bug report? I tried just passing in a ClassRef at the Invoice level but generated an error. I'll be curious to learn if there are any changes related to this.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are a Plus subscriber and have Classes enabled in your company preferences.

You can set a class ref on every invoice line. It is basically a ReferenceType. Here is an example with a class used in an invoice.

```
<Invoice domain="QBO" sparse="false">
  <Id>89</Id>
  <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2014-01-23T10:40:56-08:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2014-01-23T10:40:56-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <DocNumber>1001</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2014-01-23</TxnDate>
  <Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <Description>sales description</Description>
    <Amount>100.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef name="Sales">1</ItemRef>
      <ClassRef name="class3">300500000000000000102</ClassRef>
      <UnitPrice>100</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Amount>100.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SubTotalLineDetail />
  </Line>
  <CustomerRef name="foobar">17</CustomerRef>
  <SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
  <DueDate>2014-02-22</DueDate>
  <TotalAmt>100.00</TotalAmt>
  <ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>false</ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>
  <PrintStatus>NeedToPrint</PrintStatus>
  <EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
  <Balance>100.00</Balance>
  <Deposit>0</Deposit>
  <AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
  <AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
  <AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
  <AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - in the GUI, there's an option to set the Class on the transaction *as a whole*, not just per line.

Comment: Ok, I only see class at Line level in my view.

Comment: In V2 it's posible to specify the Class at the Invoice level. Is this also an issue with what version of QBO you're using? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm using V3. That matches what I see in QBO as well.

Answer (score 1):

ClassRef can appear at either transaction level or line level based on the Class Tracking setting of  setting in Company preferences and the state the setting was in when the invoice was created. The docs need to be corrected.